# Difference between assigning function to variable or not

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a worked on a couple different projects and I have seen two different ways of creating jQuery/JavaScript functions.

The first:

```
function testFunction(){

};
```

The second:

```
var testFunction = function (){

};
```

Is there a difference between these?

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/nfe/ read this

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The main difference is the first one (a function declaration) is *hoisted* to the top of the scope in which it is declared, whereas the second one (a function expression) is not.

This is the reason you are able to call a function that has been declared after you call it:

```
testFunction();
function testFunction() {}
```

You can't do that with a function expression, since the assignment happens in-place:

```
testFunction();
var testFunction = function() {}; //TypeError
```

There is also a third form (a *named* function expression):

```
var testFunction = function myFunc() {};
```

In this case, the identifier `myFunc` is only in scope inside the function, whereas `testFunction` is available in whatever scope it is declared. *BUT* (and there's always a but when it comes to Internet Explorer) in IE below version 9 the `myFunc` identifier wrongly leaks out to the containing scope. Named function expressions are useful when you need to refer to the calling function (since [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) is deprecated).

---

Also note that the same is true for variable declarations:

```
console.log(x); //undefined (not TypeError)
var x = 10;
```

You can imagine that the JavaScript engine interprets the code like this:

```
var x; //Declaration is hoisted to top of scope, value is `undefined`
console.log(x);
x = 10; //Assignment happens where you expect it to
```

Comment: +1 ***Knowledge*** I did not know this is how it worked. I have run into issues with `var testFunction = function (){}` and didn't know why. This totally makes sense.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Right. I'll add that in.