# jQuery - custom trigger not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling

In my form, on 'keyup' - I am triggering a custom event. But it not works. I need to receive the value from the trigger too.

here is my code :

```
(function($){

    $(document).on('nameEnter', showName);

    input = $('#name');
    input.on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.event.trigger({
            type:'nameEnter',
            value:value,
            time: new Date()
        });
    });

    var showName = function(params){
        console.log('params is', params); //nothing happening!
    };

}(jQuery));
```

[Live Demo is Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/3gwebtrain/27DAV/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define showName before you pass it to the .on method:

```
var showName = function(params){
    console.log('params is', params);
};

$(document).on('nameEnter', showName);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the function properly for it to work:

```
(function($){

    $(document).on('nameEnter', showName);

    input = $('#name');
    input.on('keyup', function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $.event.trigger({
            type:'nameEnter',
            value:value,
            time: new Date()
        });
    });

}(jQuery));

    function showName (params){
        console.log('params is', params.value);
    };
```

[You can check it in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/27DAV/1/)

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with is the way you declare your function

Change this

```
          var showName = function(params){
            console.log('params is', params); //nothing happening!
          };
```

with

```
            function showName (params){
              console.log('params is', params.value);
           };
```

this has to do with the scope of function ready more here

[Difference between assigning function to variable or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146814/difference-between-assigning-function-to-variable-or-not)

The main difference is the first one (a function declaration) is hoisted to the top of the scope in which it is declared, whereas the second one (a function expression) is not.

That is why you are unable to access the function expression before hand