# Javascript - unable to understand function parentheses

Tags: javascript

I am confused how the way functions are called. Sometimes they are given in `functionName()` format and sometimes just the name, `functionName`.

For example in HTML, when we call `onclick="functionName()"` but in Javascript we just pass function `functionName` as argument to another function.
`setTimeout(functionName, 1000);`

Here's an example from a book, suppose we have to pass a callback function with arguments.

```
var mySetTimeout = function(callback, delay){
  var dollars = 100;
  callback(dollars);
};
var onCompletion = function(dollars,name){
  console.log(name + ": Here's your $" + dollars);
};
var getMoney = function (name) {
  var requestB = mySetTimeout(function(dollars){
    onCompletion(dollars,name);
  }, 1000);
};
getMoney('Simon');
```

Here in **mySetTimeout** function we are passing callback as an argument but with nothing in it. But later on in mySetTimeout function we are passing callback function with argument.

Can anyone explain me the all the cases? Thanks!

Comment: AS i can see in MD_N http://mdn.beonex.com/en/DOM/window.setTimeout.html you can pass a function to SetTimeOut , o try to review your code, pur logs for it.

Comment: You can see the difference between function declaration and expression in this link. https://stackoverflow.com/a/11146853/1856338

Comment: Sorry, but that's how callback functions work :)

Comment: You understood correctly: "*we just pass function as argument to another function*". It takes a reference to the function object and passes it around. Later, inside `mySetTimeout`, when `callback` is used with the parenthesis, it is actually *called*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand a few things about callback functions, anonymous functions etc to get this idea. It's very common to use anonymous functions in JS.

I will try to explain you in the simplest possible way. In your code, in the first line: refer my comment.

```
var mySetTimeout = function(callback, delay){ // Note 01
  var dollars = 100;
  callback(dollars); // Note 02
};
```

**Note 01:** Here, callback is nothing more than a string parameter. It's not a function, but a function name. You tell that you want to run a function called "callback" and you pass that name. Then you run that function by simply calling, `callback()`, where "callback" is the parameter you passed above to this function.

**Note 02:** Here, you actually run a function with that name you defined above.

In this line of code,

```
  var requestB = mySetTimeout(function(dollars){
    onCompletion(dollars,name);
  }, 1000);
```

You can see that instead of "callback" string parameter, you have defined the function itself because inside the "mySetTimeout" function, it runs that first parameter as a function.

So basically, you could have done the same as below:

```
var myCallbackFunction = function(dollars){
    onCompletion(dollars,name);
  };

var requestB = mySetTimeout(myCallbackFunction, 1000);
```

Now you see that first parameter holds a function and when that is invoked inside the "mySetTimeout" function, the function you defined above will be actually run. Basically, I tried to explain that you can hold a function within a variable. That's the purpose of anonymous functions / lambda functions.

I tried to explain you this in the simplest way. Hope this helps. Google "JavaScript anonymous functions" and you will have enough things to learn.

Comment: Thanks. Summing up, a function is referenced without parentheses(when passed as an argument in other function) just with its name `functionName` no matter how many arguments it has. Thanks again! Will surely Google this. :)

Comment: It's not the function that you are referencing..You assign the function to a variable, and you pass that variable as the parameter.  say var func = function(){..}. Now, variable "func" holds a function. You can pass this variable around, and you can destroy it later if you don't want. That's the whole purpose of anonymous functions (to not clutter the global namespace with functions that you would run once and forget.)

Answer (score -2):

The **mySetimeout** function can be used in 2 ways:

Syntax:

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
```

or

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is totally different than what I have asked.

Comment: I am not asking about the parameters, but rather the difference between how function is referenced with and without parameters.